# Should I await all the time in firebase function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's assume a firestore insertion:

```
db.collection('activity').doc("0").set(newActivity)
```

Lint does not show "Promises must be handled appropriately" or any other message for that instruction

Should I await it?

I'm terminating the function after the insertion by sending a response at the end.

Comment: If you want to make sure that it saved to the database correctly then yes you should use either await or a promise. But if you don't have any other action to perform after setting value to database I don't see a reason why you should await and instead you can .catch(). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For **any** function that returns a promise, if you need to do something after the async work completes, you should use `then()` or `await`.  You should also generally assume that any async work can fail, which means you should also `catch()` or `try`/`catch` with it.  Firestore APIs aren't any different than other APIs in this respecct.

Comment: I don't need to do anything after the set. My concern is about sending a response to the client (res.send(true)). Does the set complete normally?

Comment: If you're talking about an HTTP type function, you should always wait until all async work is complete before sending a response to the client, otherwise the work may not finish.